# PHP Saving BootStrap Form Data (Without Database)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

Am Currently Working on A music Review Website At the Minute As a Project am Looking to create a User Profile System which when users log in allows them to Review the products on the site. For Pure learning Purposes I Don't want to Store the Login Details on a Database I Want to Store them as a PHP file and read them from their What would be a good way of going about this (New to This)

My Code Below Shows The information I need To save And also validate at Login:

```
    <div class="container">
   <div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"
            method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="forename" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Forename</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="forename"

               name="forename" placeholder="Forename" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

That's Just an Example of one Part of the Form But how Can I Capture The data and Store it as a PHP file ?

Many thanks

Comment: i think u should store the data in txt file and later use that data to validate user. There are various built in function in php to read and write data, namely fopen, fread. just google it and u will get alot of help.

Comment: Thanks for that ill take a look

Comment: As Niraj said you can put your data in .txt files which would be saved locally.
$data;
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $data);

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a text file or you can store it formatted as xml. It would be easy to process data from xml formatted file, since to validate login, you need to read specific username and password set.

To create a file, you can use the fopen() in php. (you need to create a handler variable for that, say $handle)

$handle = fopen('directory/filename.extension', r);

Lets say that you have the user data stored in $var. To write it to that file:

fwrite($handle, $var);

Once you write the data, you can close the file using:

fclose($handle);

Tips:
I guess you dont want to use database now. So here are few tips:

If you want to store the data in text file, split each data set of data with a special symbol. So that you can use the explode() function to convert that data into array for further processing. In the same way, you can use some other symbol or charecter to divide property and value pairs (like username : someusername) , and you can use explode again to extract specific data.

Also, you can put the data in a csv file (comma seperated values, can be opened in ms excel).
fgetcsv() and fputcsv() will read and write the data to csv file, and they get each line of file as array and write an array as one row/line in csv file respectively.

Hope this helps.